How to create a chart in Highcharts using this mock?
I have a mock available on the desired highchart that i need to generate. But i am not sure how to achieve this. Can somebody please help? I am new to highcharts and not sure how to approach this? Trying to build this comp in React.


I found this online - https://jsfiddle.net/mKABN/1/. But here the line intesect exactly at some data point. But in my case I am not sure where the line charts will intersect

It’s depend on what is your input, share with and we can help. check this package

The data looks like "timeSeries": [
{
"time": "2024-01-01",
"value": 12,
"delta": 0.5
},
{
"time": "2024-01-02",
"value": 12,
"delta": 0.5
}
]. I have two sets of it for the two charts. The deilta i need to add on the chart. The chart i need to plot with the value

To achieve the same result as on the image, you will need to combine two line series and dumbbell https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/dumbbell-series . It will require parsing data first to use upper and lower data (after delta changes). To build it in React use Highcharts React Integration: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react
